# Modifing listing of email items

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm building up an addin for outlook. I am trying to find out how to modify the listing of an email item, would anyone know how to create this tag?
[image: extract from clio addin]

Would anyone know how to modify the email to show the listing as such?

it should look like this

[image]

Comment: Maybe ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)? General computing questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @DavidMakogon this is a programming question how to create something like that with an Outlook add-in.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - as written, it's *not* a programming question. That is: it's a general set of requirements, and a "how to do it?" No code, no attempt, no specific issue. Still off-topic.

Comment: @DavidMakogon the OP wrote - I'm building up an addin for outlook. So, that is only your imagination that it is not a programming question. Try to google what Office add-ins are.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - look at [Why is "Can someone help me" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). The OP did not ask a programming question. They posted specs and left it up the Community. Literally no programming question - no imagination needed. I know what an Office add-in is - no need to tell me how to search. This is not an issue of definitions. It's 100% an issue of "requirements posted with no programming question."

Comment: Ok, the question was clear to me.

Comment: If you are trying to use categories, you can use the category APIs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/categories

Answer (score 1):

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for that. You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Looks like the screenshot comes from OWA. In that case you may consider developing a web browser add-on for such tasks.

Comment: Aside from the OP's question being off-topic, what you posted isn't an answer - it's a suggestion to vote on something (this should be a comment, not an answer).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I don't think so. My post clearly answers the question posted.